# Proof that the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge in $(0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Consider the metric space $((0, 1), |\cdot|)$. I'd like to show the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge in $(0, 1)$.

I wrote the following proof by contradiction: Suppose $\lim_n 1/n =a\in (0, 1)$. By the archimedean property  there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$Na>1.$$
Now, corresponding to $\varepsilon:=a-1/N$ there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\forall n\geq n_0\Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon=a-\frac{1}{N}.$$
In particular

$$n\geq n_0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{N}<\frac{1}{n}.$$
But this is an absurd, for instance, if $n\geq \max\{N, n_0\}$ it follows $n\geq N$ and therefore $1/n\leq 1/N$ although $n\geq n_0$.

I have two questions concerning this proof.

(1) Is it correct?

(2) Is there a direct proof for that fact using the definition of convergence of sequences?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is correct.
2. Yes. Let $a\in(0,1)$. There is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\frac a2$ and therefore $n\geqslant N\implies\frac1n<\frac a2$. So, the open interval $\left(\frac a2,1\right)$ (to which $a$ belongs) only contains finitely many elements of the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and therefore $a$ is not the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other approaches:

Limits are unique in $\mathbb{R}$ (it is a T2 space) and $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. It is straightforward to show that the unique limit of the sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$) is $0$.

If the sequence converged to a limit in $(0,1)$, it would converge to the same limit in $\mathbb{R}$, hence the sequence does not converge in the space $(0,1)$.

An alternative, which is similar to the method in the question, is to show that for any $a \in (0,1)$ there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $|a-{1 \over n}| \ge \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.

In particular, note that $|a-{1 \over n}| \ge {a \over 2}$ for $n  \ge {2 \over a}+1$.